# Regex to match spaces except for spaces inside url pattern

Tags: regex, spaces

Hi I'm new to regex and I am trying to use this to catch spaces `\s{2,}` in the junk but **NOT** including the spaces inside the `"url":"https://x.com/a/C25/XPS  - Connection - May 2013.docx"`. Currently, I have a scenario where url is not encoded yet so it may contain spaces inside.

Sample Text:

```
"startofjunk      junkjunkjunkjunk","url":"https://x.com/a/C25/XPS  - Connection - May 2013.docx","contentsource":"AX","returpath":null,"detailpath":"https://ax.sample.com/Rep>ositories/form.aspx?path=C25/96/99&mode=Read","detailspath2":"samplepath"
```

Desired Text:

```
"startofjunk junkjunkjunkjunk","url":"https://x.com/a/C25/XPS  - Connection - May 2013.docx","contentsource":"AX","returpath":null,"detailpath":"https://ax.sample.com/Rep>ositories/form.aspx?path=C25/96/99&mode=Read","detailspath2":"samplepath"
```

please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

This regex will find an replace all multiple spaces with a single space, and will bypass the url section. In a sequence of X number of spaces, the first space is placed into group 1 which is fed to the output as `\1` and the additional spaces are ignored. The URL section is bypassed because if it is encountered as part of the `|` or statement, then it is captured into group 2 which is then injected back into the output by the `\2` replacement.

Regex: `(\s)\s*|("url":"[^"]*")`, Replace with: `\1\2`

[image]

## Source String

```
"startofjunk        junkjunkjunkjunk","url":"https://x.com/a/C25/XPS - Connection - May 2013.docx","contentsource":"AX","returpath":null,"detailpath":"https://ax.sample.com/Rep>ositories/form.aspx?path=C25/96/99&mode=Read","detailspath2":"samplepath"
```

## PHP example

This php example is included to simply show that the regex works

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
echo preg_replace('/(\s)\s*|("url":"[^"]*")/im','\1',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
"startofjunk junkjunkjunkjunk","url":"https://x.com/a/C25/XPS - Connection - May 2013.docx","contentsource":"AX","returpath":null,"detailpath":"https://ax.sample.com/Rep>ositories/form.aspx?path=C25/96/99&mode=Read","detailspath2":"samplepath"
```

Comment: Hi @Denomales Thanks! what should we add to modify the matching spaces to a single space? Like this: "startofjunk junkjunkjunkjunk"

Answer (score 0):

Use a look-ahead to assert that your spaces occur *before* "url". Also use a look-behind so your whole match is the excess spaces:

```
(?<=\s)\s+(?=.*"url":)
```

To remove excess spaces, replace the entire match with blank (ie nothing), or if your application language allows it, *remove* the entire match.